# Page redirect in tapestry5

Tags: java, tapestry

I am working in web application using tapestry framework. I have following pages a,b,c,d and Index in my application.
In Index page, check some condition and redirect to a particular page.
My code,

```
if(null != cookieVal) {
    if(cookieVal.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
        return A.class;
    } else if(cookieVal.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
        return B.class;
    } else if(cookieVal.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
        return C.class;
    } else if(cookieVal.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        return D.class;
    }
}
```

Here conditions are increased if pages are increased. How can I optimize this condition check and redirect to particular page.

Comment: you could lookup from a `Map<String, Class<?>>`

Answer (score 1):

Return a link created with PageRenderLinkSource service.

```
@Inject
private PageRenderLinkSource pageRenderLinkSource;

...

   if(null != cookieVal) {
    return pageRenderLinkSource.createPageRenderLink(cookieValue);
   }

...
```

---

http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/PageRenderLinkSource.html